# ¿Cómo puedo cargar en un RichTextBox cualquier archivo de texto en C#?

Tags: c#

Necesito hacer un programa para que abra archivos de de texto  y los imprima en richtexbox.

Tengo esto pero no funciona:

```cs
FileStream ObjArchivo = new FileStream(Path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
```

Answer (score 3):

El propio RichTextBox cuenta con el método [LoadFile()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.loadfile(v=vs.110).aspx) para poder cargar el archivo que selecciones.

[How to: Load Text into a RichTextBox Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228352(v=vs.90).aspx)

Usarías:

```cs
OpenFileDialog openFile1 = new OpenFileDialog();
openFile1.Filter = "Text Files|*.txt";

if (openFile1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    richTextBox1.LoadFile(openFile1.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si necesitas todo el texto, puedes usar la clase `File`

```
using System.IO;

// ...

var texto = File.ReadAllText("archivo.txt");
```

Este método te devuelve todo como un solo `string`